# Printing on a printer ( windows platform 32bit )

Tags: c++, visual-c++, printing

I am unaware how to print documents using `c++`. Could you please tell me if there are some good tutorials available that teach printing on a printer in c++. I am targeting windows platform and 32bit `OS` .

Actually i am looking forward to print files that my program stores in the hard drive. I had found some tutorials but they don't explain the function used.

Answer (score 6):

MSDN has a tutorial on how to print from a windows program, it may be what your looking for. It goes through how to gather the printer information, start the printer thread, render the data and then close the printing thread. Hopefully it helps you out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819270(v=vs.85).aspx